# How to display large amount of information properly without cramping too much in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, graph, charts, chart.js

I am trying to display live data that gets very large. The problem is that the lines look very cramped... I don't want all the data points to be on the spot, and I can loose a bit accuracy here and there...

**Here it is: **
[image]

So, is there a way, I can clean up the lines in my chart?
Preferably, without deleting the starting elements in the data.

**Here is the code: **

```js
  var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "line",
    data: {
      labels: [new Date()],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "# of Votes",
          data: [Math.random()],
          borderWidth: 4,
        },
      ],
    },
    options: {
      elements: {
        line: {
          backgroundColor: "#22ff2252",
          borderColor: "#00de00",
          fill: true,
          borderWidth: 10,
          tension: 0.05,
        },
        point: {
          radius: 0,
          borderWidth: 0,
          pointStyle: "triangle",
        },
      },
      scales: {
        y: {
          beginAtZero: false,
        },
        xAxis: {
          type: "time",
          ticks: {
            source: "auto",
            autoSkip: true,
            maxTicksLimit: 10,
            maxRotation: 0,
            minRotation: 0,
          },
          time: {
            unit: "second",
          },
        },
      },
    },
  });

  setInterval(() => {
    colors = ["#00de00", "#de0000"];
    myChart.options.elements.line.borderColor =
      colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    myChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(Math.random());
    var today = new Date();
    var time =
      today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
    myChart.data.labels.push(new Date());
    myChart.update();
  }, 2500);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.3.2/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.27.0"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-moment@0.1.1"></script>
<div style="height: 90%; width: 90%">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [decimation plugin](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/decimation.html) that lets you define the `'lttb'` or `'min-max'` algorithm option.

[LTTB](https://github.com/sveinn-steinarsson/flot-downsample) decimation reduces the number of data points significantly. This is most useful for showing trends in data using only a few data points.

[Min/max](https://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/F694FFEEA0ACF282862576020075F784) decimation will preserve peaks in your data but could require up to 4 points for each pixel. This type of decimation would work well for a very noisy signal where you need to see data peaks.

Please take a look at the [Data Decimation Sample](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/advanced/data-decimation) and see how it works.

Comment: Hey, I read the docs and thought it was the solution, but I am not able to implement it, Do, I need to install the plugin in some way? because I have defined the plugin decimation in the config object but it doesn't seem to work for me...

Comment: Try adding `parsing: false` to your `dataset`. Also make sure, all other requirements are met (see. https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/decimation.html#requirements).

Comment: Yea, but do you think there is a way to decimate even when parsing is on?